# Getting Fatal Error while creating order from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, create-order

I am getting below error on Select customer step after clicking on Create Order button.

**Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object in /app/code**

**/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php**

```
    public function getMethodInstance()
    {
        $method = parent::getMethodInstance();
        return $method->setStore($this->getQuote()->getStore());//Error line
    }
```

I googled this error and found that if we truncate or delete rows from table **sales_flat_quote_payment** it works perfectly.

But I can't do this on my live site. Is there any other solution?

Comment: have you updated stores?

Comment: I have made no change in stores. Please see my updated question for code in which error is coming.

Comment: Please put below code :  public function getMethodInstance()
    {
        $method = parent::getMethodInstance();
        if($this->getQuote()->getStore()) {
   return $method->setStore($this->getQuote()->getStore());
        }else {
         return $method->setStore(1);
        }
    }

Comment: Now I am getting same error on line if($this->getQuote()->getStore())

Answer (score 1):

> Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object

it means there is some issue with $this->getQuote() function and this->getQuote() return non object result might be because of some issue with table

> sales_flat_quote_payment